# Selecting image link

Tags: html, css, image, wordpress, url

I want a border under links, but not under image links:

```
#post .content img{border:3px solid #2E92AB;}
#post .content img a{border-bottom:0px;}
#post .content a{border-bottom:1px solid #2E92AB;}
```

Can't figure out how to select the image `a`.

I want a border (`border:3px solid #2E92AB;`) around the image, but it just adds an additional border which I don't want.

Here's an example: http://www.disgeae.nl/wordpress/uitleg-wordpress-installatie

Comment: Why are we having to guess your HTML? If you show it to us, we can offer better answers.

Comment: Edited my post a bit, which makes it more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Issue is fixed:

Your image links are applying a specific class "**fancybox**" to their `anchor` tags

```
#post .content a.fancybox { border: none; }
```

I've checked this and its working for your, indeed remember to define this CSS rule after your defined ones i.e. it should be like this:

```
#post .content img { border: 3px solid #2E92AB; }
#post .content a { border-bottom: 1px solid #2E92AB; }
#post .content a.fancybox { border: none; }
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
#post > .content > a { border-bottom: 1px solid #2E92AB; }
```

Answer (score 0):

you probably want to change

```
#post .content img a{border-bottom:none;}
```

to

```
#post .content a img {border-bottom:none;}
```

since it is not correct to nest a link inside an image

otherwise it would help to see your html

**Edit**

try changing

```
#post .content img{border:3px solid #2E92AB;}
#post .content img a{border-bottom:1px solid #2E92AB;}
#post .content a{border-bottom:1px solid #2E92AB;}
```

to

```
#post .content a img{border-bottom:none;}
#post .content a{border-bottom:1px solid #2E92AB;}
```

Comment: Doesn't work, removes the actual border(-bottom) around the image.

Comment: hmmm well I'm confused then, in your original question when you say "but it just adds an additional border which I don't want" - what do you actually mean by that?

Comment: http://www.disgeae.nl/example.png the border just above the red line, not the one around the image.

Comment: ok, that border is coming from #post .content a { border-bottom: 1px solid #2E92AB; } so you could set that to border-bottom: none but this will turn it off for text links also. If that is not what you want, are you able to add a class to the <a> tag that the image is inside?

Comment: Already set it to none. And no I can't. Since it's a CMS on working with. (WordPress)